# Weighted sampling sequences to train a neural network in CNTK

Tags: cntk

I am training a LSTM on weighted sequences with CNTK. I started from the following example of language understanding: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb

To train the network, they produce a CNTK Text Format (CTF) file like :

```
19  |S0 178:1 |# BOS      |S1 14:1 |# flight  |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |S0 770:1 |# show                         |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |S0 429:1 |# flights                      |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |S0 444:1 |# from                         |S2 128:1 |# O
```

I have a **weight** associated to each sequence. Therefore, I generated the following output:

```
19  |weight 10 |S0 178:1 |# BOS      |S1 14:1 |# flight  |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |weight 10 |S0 770:1 |# show                         |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |weight 10 |S0 429:1 |# flights                      |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |weight 10 |S0 444:1 |# from                         |S2 128:1 |# O
```

I want to take the `weight` into account when training the network. One possible way to take it into account is modifying the loss function as follow: I multiply the cross entropy by the weight of an instance.

```
def create_criterion_function(model):
    labels = Placeholder(name='labels')
    weight = Placeholder(name='weight')
    ce   = weight * cross_entropy_with_softmax(model, labels)
    errs = classification_error      (model, labels)
    return combine ([ce, errs]) # (features, labels) -> (loss, metric)
```

However, when I have many sequences, the network seem to not learn. I have been told that this is a case of [catastrophic forgetting](http://catastrophic%20forgetting):

> Catastrophic forgetting (also: catastrophic interference) is a term, often used in connectionist literature, to describe a common problem with many traditional artificial neural network models. It refers to the catastrophic loss of previously learned responses, whenever an attempt is made to train the network with a single new (additional) response.

Another solution might be that I could sample the instances in the minibatch according to the weight: sequences with higher weight should appear more often in the minibatches. Is there a way to do it in CNTK?

Comment: One small note: just like the S1 field for sequence intent, because the same weight applies to each element in a sequence, you only need to put it once on the first line of each sequence.

Comment: So it is just a representation option. Would it be equivalent to repeating the weight: ie the weight is multiplied for each char? I am also thinking that this could actually give more weight on average to longer sequences

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is correct. However, note that scaling up the objective by 10 will scale up your gradient by 10 for these samples. Before looking into catastrophic forgetting, I would first try reducing your learning rate by 10, as to bring back the gradient steps into the same range as before.

Comment: So would I reduce the learning rate by a constant factor? How can I find this factor if every weight is different for each sequence?

Comment: Unfortunately this is still a matter of try-and-error. I would scale the learning rate down by a factor in the range of the average weight, and then experiment with that value *2 and /2, and see which of the three configurations works best.